# Finding parents of Elizabeth Razor (b.1811) who married Fielding Hash?

Tags: united-states, baptism-records, illinois, 1810s

My 2nd great grandmother was Elizabeth Razor b. 1811.

I have a first name for her mother, Lydia, taken from her marriage record to Fielding Hash but no father's name.

Does anyone have information about Elizabeth Razor's parents?

Comment: Andrea, welcome to Genealogy.SE. To get a useful answer to your question, you need to add where your grandmother was born, and be more specific about what you're asking. I'd guess you're asking how you can go about finding Elizabeth's parents, in which case you should also tell us what you've already tried, as per: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Being I do not have all of the background (as in location, was Elizabeth her first or middle or nick name) I did some picking at the information and came up with the following:

With so little information this may be a bit error prone but this is what I found in about 20 minutes of poking around, it is at least a lead:

Theory: In 1830 Elizabeth was already married to Fielding Hash and had 2 young children, having a marriage date would be useful to confirm.

Lydia Rasure listed as head of Household in 1830: Morgan, Illinois
1x Male <5, 2x Male 10-14, 1x Female 10-14, 1x Female 20-49. Total Household 5. 
(No elder male)

I found a Fielding Hash in the 1830 Sangamon Co, Illinois Census which is the adjoining county to Morgan Co. Illinois with town seats 47 miles apart. Though that household has 2 children under 5 (1m/1F), one between 10-15, and one under 20. The eldest male Fielding Hash is also listed as under 20. So the one between 10-15 could be a sibling.

I found several references to a Elizabeth Russell and a Fielding Hash but nothing Razor, but I did not go as far as trying to see if this is the same Henry. I did also find land purchase records for Fielding.

I assume you are the [creator of this record](http://records.ancestry.com/elizabeth_razer_records.ashx?pid=8702082) implying Elizabeth was married 3 times on Ancestry.com. This amount of detail would have been helpful as well in your post and I found it towards the tail end of my effort.

If you update your answer with more detail of what you know we can probably further help.